# Duplicate line and comment out old one

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I often need to edit a line but comment out the old one.

Is it possible to create a key binding for these commands in Sublime Text 2?

- duplicate current line
- comment out the top line
- move the cursor to the bottom line

Comment: Possibly better suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the comment syntax is defined for the file type, you can use a simple macro (though even if it's not you could do it, the macro would just be a little more involved). Anyways, save the following in `Packages/User` as whatever you like. Be sure the extension is `.sublime-macro` though.

```
[
    {
        "args":
        {
            "block": false
        },
        "command": "toggle_comment"
    },
    {
        "command": "duplicate_line"
    },
    {
        "args":
        {
            "block": false
        },
        "command": "toggle_comment"
    }
]
```

Then, create a key binding like the following.

```
{ "keys": ["f12"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/User/<the file name>.sublime-macro"} },
```

Of course, change the `keys` and `<the file name>` as appropriate.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!
I couldn't get the file path to work at first, but then I changed `res://Packages/User/<the file name>.sublime-macro` to `Packages/User/<the file name>.sublime-macro`.