# Vim copy line and comment out old line

Tags: vim

I'm trying to achieve the same thing asked here, but in Vim.

[Duplicate line and comment out old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716708/duplicate-line-and-comment-out-old-one)

Basically I want to yank line, comment out the old one, paste new one, and keep cursor at the beginning of new line and end in insert mode.

For example:

```
def func (param)
```

will change to:

```
//def func (param)
def func (param)
```

I recorded a macro for it, put it into `.vimrc` and I'm using it via `@y`

```
" copy-and-comment-line macro
" yank line, comment out original line, move cursor at the begining
" of copied line and end in insert mode
let @y='yypkui//kdklkl'
```

(I'm not sure it will work for you as it contains unprintable `~@` characters which code block won't display)

Macro works, but is there a built-in command in vim that I can achieve same thing with?

Comment: What's wrong with your macro?

Comment: @romainl Nothing in fact, although I just thought that this is more common action among vim users and therefore there could be more elegant (shorter and more readable) set of keystrokes than my recorded macro.

Comment: A macro doesn't need to be readable and it's a lot quicker than any non-existing generic solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This mapping should do it for you:

```
nnoremap YOURKEY YI//<esc>p
```

- The cursor will be on the pasted line.
- replace `YOURKEY` by a key (or keys) you like
- **Note** that this answer works only for your example, `//`style comment. If you want it to be generic solution, you have to build a function, in this function check the filetype, and decide which comment style should be used. There is no good built-in solution so far, but you can check the [NERDCommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter/blob/master/plugin/NERD_commenter.vim#L71) or [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) plugins to see how they achieve this, or you can install one of them (or a similar plugin) and call it's function in your mapping.

Comment: Yeah that's great if that's the comment syntax for the language that you happen to be working in. If, however, you work on Python or shellscripts (for instance) all this will do is insert a syntax error.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist the answer is based on the OP's codes. I didn't say it will work all kinds of "comment styles"

Comment: There's no language tag here, the linked question is language agnostic, indeed vim itself is language agnostic, and that is listed as "an example". Anyway, if I found this question, this solution would not work for me.

Comment: @aragaer you should check it more carefully, `p` is right there, at the end of the map command.

Comment: @kent Thanks for your thorough answer, it works like a charm! Except one small thing - it doesn't go into insert mode after paste. But `YI//<esc>pi` will do the trick.

Comment: @two-bit-alchemist I'm aware that this is not language agnostic, just one comment style example. This was actually my second question I didn't write yet, however Kent kindly answered that already.